# The greed for rep

Tags: discussion, reputation

So in [this](https://superuser.com/q/959258/1062246) question, [this](https://superuser.com/a/959267/1062246) answer posted seems that it should totally be a comment but it is posted as an answer and has received a significant amount of upvotes, while the answer posted by [me](https://superuser.com/a/1537713/1062246) and [this person](https://superuser.com/a/1067091/1062246) should receive more upvotes as they are the actual answers which support the OP’s requirements

So, is it that I am just greedy for more rep or what I am saying makes some sense?

P.S. First question on this site went through all the rules, hope I didn’t miss any tags.

Comment: That question made the Hot Network Questions on Aug 2015. Both the other answer and yours came much later than that. HNQ inflates the post score and the rep the author receives. Regardless, it doesn't make much sense to say "this post's score should have been higher", no. You can at best persuade people to look at other answers, and vote accordingly, but there's nothing just or unjust about the post scores on that question. In this case, the OP's accept means your answer will appear on top and it will hopefully help folks in the future (and receive more upvotes)

Comment: @M.A.R. Well, at the end the future folks will be able to see it and be delighted for getting their problem solved, in that case, I am happy with no rep.

Comment: With all due respect, but what you think here is irrelevant. The counts will not be adjusted. Does it make sense for the best answers to be voted the highest? Yes. Does it always work that way? Not even close. That's life.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes, looks like it is this problem.

Comment: @Mast Life is full of ups and downs, seems that I will have to go with the flow.

Comment: @Rob Yes, looks similar.

Comment: Who are you to judge? You are the greedy one. Who demands "upvote my answers, not others". That's wrong and rude.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou No no no, I am not demanding to upvote my answer, it is just the fact that it seems to be a similar case of the fastest gun in the west problems. Please go through the answer to see if I have a valid point.

Comment: @Valay_17 i'm not sure why you consider that answer as a fastest gun in the west case. It was the only answer back in 2015 and because it hit HNQ on the same period it attracted a lot of upvotes. I'm sure rep will come if people like your answer and actually face the same issue.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Yup, I should consider the time factor, maybe it is not similar to the fastest gun. I think that I should stop worrying about the rep after all. Would it be wise to delete this question or keep it??

Comment: "while the answer posted by me and this person should receive more upvotes" - to me it sounds just like "My answer is the correct answer and should get upvotes". Unless I miss something basic.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou Yup that is my greed for sure.

Comment: The answer you believe to be a comment in 205 absolutely was an answer in the 2015.  If it was submitted as an answer in 2015 I would have flagged it as “no longer be necessary” immediately.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am aware of it, I don’t wish this question to be continued any further can I delete it somehow ?

Comment: @Valay_17 - This question is no longer eligible to be deleted

Answer (score 4):

> So, is it that I am just greedy for more rep or what I am saying makes some sense?

No need for negative judgements. Most humans have some implicit understanding of "fairness", and being treated "unfair" results in negative emotions.

Yes, your observations are correct: that first answer with 140 upvotes isn't a great answer at all. Sure, content-wise it expresses that the feature the OP asks for isn't available. But that is the thing: it is written up like a mediocre comment, nothing more.

The other two are better, and don't worry: your accepted answer will accumulate more votes, it just takes time.

You have to understand that in the end, we are all humans here. Sometimes good rules get ignored, and great content receives zero or very few upvotes. The next day, someone else puts up mediocre content, and for whatever reasons ends up with way more votes. And yes, answering on a "hot network question" can easily attract upvotes, sometimes undeserved.

That is part of posting on this network. And no, it is not always fair.

Comment: Yup that’s true, I can think of real life examples of the same ,guess I’ll have to wait 

Comment: I'm confused about your answer. I think 'you can not rename the virtual desktops in Windows 10' is **the answer** back in 2015.

Comment: @CaldeiraG After some thinking, reworded my answer a bit.